# Titanium Studio working with Vmware or VirtualBox Android 4.0.3 virtual machine

Tags: android, android-emulator, titanium, appcelerator

I am using **windows 7**. I installed **Titanium Studio** and updated it. Then i load **Android SDK** and **JAVA JDK 6**. Android API includes almost all packages. After this installations, i set **JAVA_HOME** and **android_sdk** params on **Windows System Environment** settings.

After that, i installed android virtual machine (vmware also virtualbox). I found android eth0's ip and connected to android virtual machine over windows command line as below

```
M:\SDKs\Android\platform-tools>adb kill-server

M:\SDKs\Android\platform-tools>adb connect 192.168.230.128
connected to 192.168.230.128:5555

M:\SDKs\Android\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.230.128:5555    device
```

After connected to virtual android, i created an example on Titanium Studio.
When i select **Android Devices** from **Run** menu of Titanium Studio for compiling my sample app on android virtual machine, i am getting error as below

```
[ERROR] Invalid --target value 'devıce'
```

Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: May I ask why you aren't using the usual emulator or a modified emulator like described [here (solution is for mac but is similar for Win)](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2013/04/configuring-appcelerator-titanium-to-use-intel-x86-images.html)?

Comment: That instruction is about MAC OS. i am using window. Anyway i tried to run MAC OS using virtual system but it was so slow.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question and yes i know that this is for mac but you can do the same (even easier) on windows to speed up the emulator. Just a hint if this is your intention.

Comment: My main problem is about emulator's slowly running. So i can accept your suggestion but i am new and i did'nt find good explain to apply on window. Could you show me how can i do?

Comment: [Tried this yet?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5154636/874257) Increasing the Android Device RAM worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a unicode translating problem in the TITANIUM SDK.

[Please, look this bug ticket.](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-4701)

Solution of the problem, change the language of the operating system. For example, in English (en). This is an easy method on the MAC. But it is not easy for WINDOWS.